# Load page partially via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I guess there are already posts on this topic, but I couldn't find anything with search terms like: "load page partially javascript", "content loading javascript", etc.

My question is how would you load a page to not display 100% of the content, but load it, for example, when you scroll.

Example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=de

I don't need someone to code this now, I would highly appreciate if someone just had a tutorial or anything similar on this.

Comment: jQuery load: http://api.jquery.com/load/ - just use `$(location).load('mypage.html #content', callback)`

Comment: Wouldn't that presume, that you have your content split over different files?

Comment: You need to use Ajax calls 
If you have a news website for example, you show the first 10 news then in scrolling down you make an ajax call for the news 11 to 20 then another one for the news from 21 to 30 ..

Comment: There are infinite scrolls out there - you might as well use something like php to output the correct thing and then load it in. This is simple stuff, tbh.

Comment: @ElheniMokhles what if I have an index.html with 30 news in it, how would I then tell it "on page load, load only the first 10 and later the other 10, later the last 10"?

Comment: @somethinghere I know how you could do this if you had, for example, a database. I am talking about static content in one file. If you have just one file, how can you control the content which gets loaded and the content which doesn't?

Comment: You need php(/asp/ror..) to only return x to y news in  a json format then you use ajax call to get this json and append it to our html.

Comment: You can separate it by ID and load it partially using the `id` syntax in jQuery (official DOCS: `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`). However, you don't make any wins on that as jQuery still load the entire page in one go.

Comment: @somethinghere So I can only achieve this by A) ajax calls + something which returns json/xml(f.e. php) or B) seperating content to a different html and then load it via $('').load?

Comment: Lets make this clearer: You can use this with `ajax` and _any_ returned kind of data, be it JSON, html, strings, numbers, .... There is no _requirement_ for it to be a certain type of data, although using JSON is _easy_. You will need a system in place that either a) returns just the required content (using php, asp, ... to filter 'server-side'), or you will have to make you javascript request different HTML files. That last bit is... unwieldy. You could even store everything in a PHP array and just return what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My approach for doing this was to use a combination of javascript and JQuery.  Something like this:

```
window.onScroll = checkScroll(event);

function checkScroll(event)
{
  position = $(window).scrollTop();  
  /* note the () are necessary to obtain a value that represents 
    the page vertical position, otherwise you will be just sending 
    the browser to the top, like a refresh */
  if (position == 1000)  /* some pre-determined vertical position */
  {
    $(#AnchorDiv).append(htmlString);
    /* Where AnchorDiv is the id of the element where you want to 
    insert new code, and htmlString is a javascript string which contains 
    the new HTML block.*/
  }
}
```

Note: you can also use Jquery's .position method to obtain the position of an element rather than hard-coding it like I did with the 1000 example.

I Hope this helps.  I'll be curious to see how it works out - and/or how other folks respond to this question - and/or of you find another good working alternative.